# Deadlocks in postgres transactions on update

Tags: postgresql, transactions, sql-update, deadlock

So I have a similar problem like [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245560/deadlocks-in-postgresql-when-running-update)

I assume the below will cause a deadlock, as they lock the id 1, 2 and 3 in a circle.

-- Transaction 1

```
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 1
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 2
```

-- Transaction 2

```
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 2
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 3
```

-- Transaction 3

```
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 3
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 1
```

However, what if I order the updates by id, so it will be like:

-- Transaction 1

```
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 1
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 2
```

-- Transaction 2

```
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 2
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 3
```

-- Transaction 3

```
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 1
UPDATE season_end_date SET ... WHERE id = 3
```

Will this fix the deadlock issue? I guess so, as T3 should now be able to run, and after that, T2 can run and a last T1.